# How can I save the state of a Lisp compiler?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I would like to save the state of a Lisp compiler so that I need not load my file in several minutes, but instead I would load that image in seconds.

Which Common Lisp compiler would do this favor for me?

I came to this idea as Standard ML of New Jersey does this: [Exporting Heaps](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/local/sml/common/smlguide/smlnj.htm#export).

I could not find similar in the [sbcl manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/) or the 
[ecl manual](http://ecls.sourceforge.net/new-manual/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With SBCL, use [save-lisp-and-die](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Saving-a-Core-Image). To restart the image, use the [`--core`](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Command-Line-Options) arguments.

Read carefully the caveats in the documentation.

With CLISP, use [EXT:SAVEINITMEM](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes.html#image)

Comment: oh this was really rtfm, thanks for being helpful